# Piping multiple commands to bash, pipe behavior question

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, cat, tty

I have this command sequence that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
[me@mine ~]$ (echo 'test'; cat) | bash
echo $?
1
echo 'this is the new shell'
this is the new shell
exit

[me@mine ~]$
```

As far as I can understand, here is what happens:

1. A pipe is created.
2. stdout of `echo 'test'` is sent to the pipe.
3. bash receives 'test' on stdin.

   - `echo $?` returns 1, which is what happens when you run `test` without args.
4. `cat` runs.

   - It is copying stdin to stdout.
   - stdout is sent to the pipe.
5. `bash` will execute whatever you type in, but stderr won't get printed to the screen (we used `|`, not `|&`).

I have three questions:

It looks like, even though we run two commands, we use the same pipe and `bash` process for both commands. Is that the case?

Where do the prompts go?

When something like cat uses stdin, does it take exclusive ownership of stdin as long as the shell runs, or can other things use it?

I suspect I'm missing some detail with ttys, but I'm not sure. Any help or details or `man` excerpt appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

1. Yes, there's a single pipe sending commands to a single instance of `bash`. Note:

   ```
   $ echo 'date "+%T hello $$"; sleep 1; date "+%T world $$"' | bash
   22:18:52 hello 72628
   22:18:53 world 72628
   ```
2. There are no prompts. From the man page:

   > An interactive shell is one started without non-option arguments (unless -s is specified) and without the -c option **whose standard input and error are both connected  to  terminals. PS1 is set and $- includes *i* if bash is interactive**.

   So a pipe is not an interactive shell, and therefore has no prompt.
3. Stdin and stdout can only connect to one thing at a time. `cat` will take stdin from the process that ran it (for example, your interactive shell) and send its stdout through the pipe to `bash`. If you need multiple things to be able to submit to the stdin of that `cat`, consider using a named pipe.

Does that cover it?

Comment: This was very helpful - thank you! Thank you especially for the answer to #3, it was helpful to understand exactly how the pipe and the stdin/stout work in this situation.